# meaning of から in following sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-から

Tell me please, what is から means in the following sentence?

> 本当のところを言うと、この時間に悠馬さんがここを通る**から**と、夏目さんに教えてもらったので、待っていたんです。

Thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

から means what it always means, in this case it marks a reason. It may be easier to read if you insert (mental) brackets for the quotation:

> 本当のところを言うと、「この時間に悠馬さんがここを通るから」と、夏目さんに教えてもらったので、待っていたんです。
>   Actually, I was waiting, because Natsume had told me that at this time Yũma would come by here.

Maybe 夏目 said

> 4時に悠馬さんがここを通る**から**、ここで待っていてください。
>   Yũma comes by here at 4 o'clock, **so** please wait here.

which got transformed and shortened to

> この時間に悠馬さんがここを通るから

in the quotation (marked by と) in the original sentence.